# Tensorflow: variable number of levels in a neural net model

Tags: python, tensorflow, layer

I was wondering if there is a way to implement a variable number of hidden layers in a model using tensorflow (python). I'm asking this because I don't know exactly how many levels I have to implement, I must read a file, or a variable, to get that information.
This is what I was thinking to do:

```
w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([h, w]))
self.__encoder[index] = tf.matmul(label, w)
```

So each level of __encoder contains an hidden layer, but I don't know if it works, neither how to implement the training.

Comment: Please, provide a complete example. It is not clear to me what you mean that the number of your hidden layer depends on the input.

Comment: Simply I read the number of hidden layers from a variable or a number from input, then I have to create that number of hidden layers performing a simple neuron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before giving you a reason, I want to say that tensorflow is made for static computational graph. So, this answer is for making this:

1. Reading from a file a certain number
2. Build a model with that number of hidden layers
3. Use this model and feed some other outputs

It is still not clear to me why you are reading the number of hidden layers somewhere, where hidden (or latent) means that these are hyperparameters that do not depend on your data.

Anyway, to build a different number of layers depending on a variable is simply as:

```
def layer(x, input_size, output_size):
    w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[input_size, output_size]))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([output_size]))
    return tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x,w) + b)

num_layers = ... #read somewhere
size_layers = ... #output_dimesion for each layer
h = x
for i in range(num_layers):
    h = layer(h, input_size, size_layers[i])
    input_size = size_layer[i]
```

After the loop, h has the output of the last layer.